# setTimeout. Can only update a mounted or mounting component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout

I'm new on react and I'm trying to change state after 1sec

```
export class Header extends Component {

 constructor() {
  super()
  this.state = {name: 'Will'}
 }

 render() {

  setTimeout(() => {
   this.setState({ name: 'Bob' })
  }, 2000);

  return (
    <h1>
     {this.state.name}
   </h1>
  )
 }
}
```

But is giving me this warning

> Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.
>   Please check the code for the Header component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, your `render` function should not have any side effects (such as starting a timer). Move that code in `componentDidMount`. Also, clear the timeout in `componentWillUnmount` to ensure that the timeout does not kick-in after the component has been removed. That should get rid of the error you get.